# How to update filter array without using React?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have some code, like this:

```
const filter = {
      address: 'India',
      name: 'Aleena'
    };

const users = [{
    name: 'John Doe',
    email: 'johndoe@mail.com',
    age: 25,
    address: 'USA'
  },
  {
    name: 'Aleena',
    email: 'aleena@mail.com',
    age: 35,
    address: 'India'
  },
  {
    name: 'Mark Smith',
    email: 'marksmith@mail.com',
    age: 28,
    address: 'England'
  }
];

const filteredUsers = users.filter((item) => {
  for (var key in filter) {
    if (item[key] === undefined || item[key] != filter[key])
      return false;
  }
  return true;
});
```

How can I dynamically update/change the `filter` object to allow users to choose which key:values to use in the filtering process? I know people normally use React for this kind of stuff, but I wondered if there was a "vanilla" way to do it.

Comment: Take input from `dropdown` via `javascript` and add some appropriate `eventListener` on element and store it in variable and pass that variable for `filter` condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, filter does it for you already. Filter returns a new filtered array without mutating the original array.

"Users" is the original array. "FilteredUsers" is the newly created filtered array off users.

To clone/copy the original Users array above, you can do:

let clonedArray = [...Users]

Answer (score 0):

The users array is a perfect candidate for this.  Let's say you want to add all of the users ages together.  It's pretty cool-simple.

1-  function addAges(acc,ele) {return acc + ele.age}

2-  Users.reduce(addAges, 0);

That'it. No console.log either. It'll returned the sum

Answer (score 0):

here's a very basic example in `CodeSandBox` to get an idea of what to do.

I believe it meets the requirements of your question

https://codesandbox.io/s/vanila-js-dynamic-filter-6yhhe6?file=/src/index.js